# Trying to use Notability in split-screen mode on iPad

Tags: ipad, multitasking

So for 8 years I have been using my 1st-generation iPad Mini, which cannot be upgraded past iOS 9, and therefore I have never had the chance to practice using split-screen or slideover mode (or any of the other multitasking innovations that came with iOS 12).  But I've just bought a brand-new iPad and am trying to figure out how to make the most of what ought to be a huge productivity boost.

- What I am doing:  with one app open, I swipe up from the bottom of
  the screen, press & hold Notability in my dock, and drag it to the
  right half of my screen.
- What I expect to happen:  Notability should
  fill half of the screen, and there should be a movable divider
  between the two open apps.
- What actually happens:  Notability opens
  in "slide over" mode, filling only about 1/3 to 1/4 of the screen;
  while it can be moved, it can't be resized.

What am I doing wrong?  If an app is in slide over mode, how do I get it into split-screen mode?

Comment: As of right now for other readers, GoodNotes supports split-screen and multiple instances, Notability has only split screen mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> drag it to the right half of my screen

It could be that you’re not letting go of the app far enough to the right — try dragging it to the right edge of your screen.

> with one app open

It could also be that this app you have open doesn’t support being in split screen. Try with Safari as the first app.

> If an app is in slide over mode, how do I get it into split-screen mode?

Drag the small pill-shaped handle at the top of the slide over app slightly towards the left/right edge of the screen. The app behind will move out the way for you to let go in the space.